# For multiple generators to handle Seq

Tags: scala

I'm a new to scala, and I want to unique a Seq[(Int,Int)] by the first component, my code as follow:

```
val seq = Seq((1,1), (0,1), (2,1), (0, 1), (3,1), (2,1))
val prev = -1
val uniqueSeq = for(tuple <- seq.sortBy(_._1) if !tuple._1.equals(prev); prev = tuple._1) yield tuple
```

but why the result is

```
uniqueSeq: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((0,1), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (2,1), (3,1))
```

Comment: those two `prev` are not the same. The one you declare inside the `for` comprehension is another one and you're not using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prev` in `prev = tuple._1` is a completely different variable from `val prev = -1`! Note that it compiles even though the first `prev` is `val`, i.e. immutable (it can't be changed).

If you want to use this approach, you can:

```
val seq = Seq((1,1), (0,1), (2,1), (0, 1), (3,1), (2,1))
var prev = -1
val uniqueSeq = for(tuple <- seq.sortBy(_._1) if !tuple._1.equals(prev)) yield { prev = tuple._1; tuple }
```

but it isn't the idiomatic one in Scala. I'll leave that to someone else, since I don't have enough time right now.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach:

It is a good idea to group them first. Then you can get the head of each of the groups:

```
seq.groupBy{
  case (x, _) => x
}.map {
  case (_, head :: _) => head
}.toList
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexey already explained the mistake you're making with the `prev` variable.
A more idiomatic implementation of what you're trying to do (if I got it right) is

```
val seq = Seq((1,1), (0,1), (2,1), (0, 1), (3,1), (2,1))
seq.sortBy(_._1).reverse.toMap.toList // List((0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,1))
```

The caveat is that going through a `Map` the duplicate keys will disappear.
The `reverse` is necessary, since the last occurrence of a "key" will be preserved in the Map.